# how to slideToggle an input with it's placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

guys, I wrote a code that whenever I click on a button (that plus sign) my input should slide but as you see my running code whenever I click that button first it start sliding the input until it reaches the placeholder then it starts sliding placeholder as a separate element they don't slide together so I wanted to know is there any way to fix this?that only input slides and placeholder slide with it.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<h1>LIST<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo"></div>
```

jQuery

```
    var plusSign = $("h1 i")
plusSign.on("click",function(event){
    $('input:text').slideToggle(3000);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ghost007D/aduLw0u3/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to modify your input to:

```
border: 0;        /* change */
display: block;   /* add this */
```

and to prevent animation buildups in jQuery - use `.stop()` like:

```
$('input:text').stop().slideToggle(3000);
```

and additionally to toggle your icon you could do:

```
plusSign.toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus"); // if needed
```

***[jsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aduLw0u3/4/)***

the proper way would be to create a wrapper around the input and animate that element instead; but if you're happy with the results and it's tested across browsers - you can keep it like this.

---

***To explain the issue you had:***

`.slideToggle()` does pretty much:

- animate height:
- if element has no height set it to `display: none`;

but if your element has borders - those are not animated, and will disappear as soon the element is set to `display: none;` creating the undesired *jump*.
Another issue is when animating `inline` elements - where line-height can interfere - therefore setting to `inline-block` or `block` helps - a lot.

Comment: wow thanks it worked and that minus plus sign was a great idea I used it thank you so much